# <?php the_content(); ?> to get a little more content after 'read more' inside loop

Tags: loop, excerpt, content

I want the  to give a little more content after `<!--more-->` tag inside Loop.

I saw this on wordpress codex

This script gives the content before the `<!--more-->` tag:

```
<?php 
global $more;    // Declare global $more (before the loop).
$more = 0;       // Set (inside the loop) to display content above the more tag.
the_content("More...");
?>
```

This script gives all the content including text below `<!--more-->` tag:

```
<?php 
global $more;    // Declare global $more (before the loop).
$more = 1;       // Set (inside the loop) to display all content, including text below more.
the_content();
?>
```

What I want is:

Post content until `<!--more-->` tag + a little after (2 lines approx) the `<!--more-->` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the diff between your 2 contents and then add to the first one a given number of words like this (not sure, but give it a try ;) ) :

```
global $more;
$more = 0;
$content_cut = get_the_content( '' );
$more = 1;
$content_full = get_the_content();

// Get the diff
$content_diff = str_replace( $content_cut, '', $content_full );

// Get 10 first words
$some_more_content = wp_trim_words( $content_diff, 10, 'link_more_here' );

// Add it to the end of cut content
$content_cut .= $some_more_content;

echo $content_cut;
```

The **linl_more_here** parameter is optionnal and is normaly a  tag with the permalink of your current post.